# Google Apps Script Simple Recursive Script Runs Very Slow

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I accidentally made a Google Drive folder private (by right clicking share->set to private) and it changed the permissions recursively to private...

The folder is structured like this

```
videos
--videos1
----1
------A
--------vid0192.mp4
--------vid2319.mp4
--------etc...
------B
--------vid7192.mp4
--------vid2919.mp4
--------etc...
----2
------A
--------vid0192.mp4
--------vid2319.mp4
--------etc...
------B
--------vid7192.mp4
--------vid2919.mp4
--------etc...
----3 etc...
--videos2 ...
```

There are about 500 folders inside the 'video' folder (videos1, videos2, etc...), each of which contains 5 folders (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and each of those 5 folders contain 2-3 folders (A, B, C). Each of those letter folders contain multiple files, about 5-10, usually videos.

I wrote an Apps Script to fix my terrible mistake, but to my surprise, it is running extremely slow.

Here is the code :

```js
function setAllFilesPermissions(folderId) {
  // Get the folder using the provided folderId
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  
  // Set the permissions for all files and subfolders in the current folder
  setPermissionsRecursively(folder);
}

function setPermissionsRecursively(folder) {
  // Get all files in the current folder
  var files = folder.getFiles();

  // Iterate through the files and set their permissions
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file);
    file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
  }

  // Get all subfolders in the current folder
  var subfolders = folder.getFolders();

  // Iterate through the subfolders and call the function recursively
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    var subfolder = subfolders.next();
    Logger.log(folder);
    folder.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
    setPermissionsRecursively(subfolder);
  }
}

function main() {
  setAllFilesPermissions("folder-id");
}
```

How can I make it run faster ? (or, how can I fix this permissions problem)

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your current situation, for example, how about manually sharing the folder of `videos` as "Anyone with the link"? By this, all files and subfolders under the folder of `videos` are publicly shared. If a part of the subfolders is not shared, please change the permission of `videos` to "Restricted" and change it to Anyone with the link" again. But, if I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you so much @Tanaike I already tried, but it didn't change all subfolders and file inside them. However, I didn't try to do that again by resetting it to restricted then to public. I just did. It looks like it is working!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that the process cost of your script can be reduced. But, from your situation, the above flow might be suitable. So, I proposed the method for manually operating. From your reply, I understood that your issue was resolved. I'm glad about it. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: I just did. Thanks again, you saved me from a nightmare!

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `However, if someone has an idea about the script and why it is so slow, it would be a great contribution.`, in your script, all files and folders are used. But, in this case, just only when the permission of the top folder of `videos` is changed, the permissions of all files and subfolders are also changed. So, I think that your script can be simply modified to `DriveApp.getFolderById("###folder ID of videos###").setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);`.

Comment: This is true, but I mean for recursively going through all the Drive tree from a folder ID. It could help many of us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Tanaike this issue is resolved.

Weirdly enough, changing the `videos` folder to `private` again then to `public` did work!

I did already do that, but a bug probably happened and not all files were affected. Doing that again worked like a charm.

However, if someone has an idea about the script and why it is so slow, it would be a great contribution.